# Is it sufficient to add metal flashing to shed roof to prevent further water intrusion?

Tags: roof, waterproofing, water-damage

Just bought a house in Kansas, and the shed out back looks to be homemade, with an asphalt roof, but not shingles.

Both sides show evidence of water rot where the edge of the asphalt doesn’t extend far enough over the wood of the roof to keep water from running underneath.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can I just tack on some metal or vinyl flashing to direct water a little away from the edge, to prevent further rot? Or is there a better solution an amateur can swing?

Answer (score 2):

you could try adding a drip edge like you have on the sides of the rake wall.

its what is usually used.

Comment: "Just" ? No. You have to pull the bottom row of nails to insert the flashing underneath, and then tar every single nail head throughout.

Comment: If a person is edge nailing comps, they should not be roofing.You can use roofing adhesive in place of nails when installing a drip edge and then seal/adhere the comp to the drip edge.